# GWT - Unable to find type 'com.myapp.launcher.client.LauncherInitializer' multi-module architecture

Tags: gwt, gwt-mvp

I have a project with the following structure:

```
com.myapp.gwt:
    Basic.gwt.xml
    Launcher.gwt.xml - inherits Basic.gwt.xml
    Module1.gwt.xml - inherits Basic.gwt.xml
com.myapp.gwt.ui.basic.client:
    AppActivityMapper.java
    AppHistoryManager.java
    AppPlaceHistoryMapper.java
    BasicInitializer.java - this is a daddy class for all entry points
    MainClientFactory.java
    MainClientFactoryImpl.java
com.myapp.gwt.ui.launcher.client: - all the stuff for the launcher module is here
    LauncherInitializer.java (extends BasicInitializer, launcher module's EntryPoint)
com.myapp.gwt.ui.launcher.client.places:
    Places and activities for the launcher module
com.myapp.gwt.ui.module1.client: - all the stuff for the module1 module is here
    Module1Initializer.java (extends BasicInitializer, module1 module's EntryPoint)
com.myapp.gwt.ui.module1.client.places:
    Places and activities for the module1 module
com.myapp.gwt.shared:
    Stuff shared between the client and the server (interfaces, dtos)
com.myapp.gwt.server:
    Code that works only on the server
```

what i have in my Basic.gwt.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.1.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.3.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module  rename-to='myapp'>
    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />

    <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet. You can change -->
    <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting -->
    <!-- any one of the following lines. -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean' />

    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.place.Place" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.activity.Activity" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.editor.Editor" />

    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
    <source path='ui.basic.client' />
    <source path='shared' />

    <replace-with class="com.myapp.gwt.ui.basic.client.ClientFactoryImpl">
        <when-type-is class="com.myapp.gwt.ui.basic.client.ClientFactory" />
    </replace-with>

<set-configuration-property name="UiBinder.useSafeHtmlTemplates" value="true" />
</module>
```

what i have in my Launcher.gwt.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.1.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.3.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module  rename-to='launcher'>

    <!-- Other module inherits -->
    <inherits name="com.myapp.gwt.Basic" />

    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
    <source path="ui.launcher.client"></source>

    <!-- Specify the app entry point class. -->
    <entry-point class='com.myapp.gwt.ui.launcher.client.LauncherInitializer' />

</module>
```

None of my classes residing inside the `com.myapp.gwt.ui.basic.client` package have reference to any of the classes inside the other module packages. The other module packages on the other hand have lots of references to the basic module and some of the classes even extend the classes inside the basic package.

The problem is that i'm getting this error during compiling to javascript launcher module:

```
[TRACE] [launcher] - Finding entry point classes
[ERROR] [launcher] - Unable to find type 'com.myapp.gwt.ui.launcher.client.LauncherInitializer'
[ERROR] [launcher] - Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
[ERROR] [launcher] - Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
[ERROR] [launcher] - Failed to load module 'launcher' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0' at localhost:61253
```

Also please tell me if you see something worth changing in the stuff i've done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a quick guess: did you try : `<source path='ui/basic/client' />`